# Linux Script Command Ignores Exit Code on Signal Interrupt

Tags: scripting, signals

I am using the script command to run a C program that handles SIGINT signals and just exits gracefully. A small example of my C code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int interruptReceived = 0;

void handleInterrupt(int signalNumber)
{
    printf("Interrupt received!\n");
    interruptReceived = 1;
    return;
}
int main(void)
{
    signal (SIGINT,handleInterrupt);

    while(!interruptReceived)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

This works ok when I run the application directly and do a ctrl + c

```
#> ./myApp; echo $?
^CInterrupt received!
0
```

However, doing the same with the Linux `script` command returns an exit code of 1, even though the process itself should exit gracefully, since I explicitly used `exit(0)`

```
#> script -qefc ./myApp; echo $?
^CInterrupt received!
1
```

The exit code will stay at 1 no matter how many operations are done by the code after the SIGINT was received. It seems that the signal is cached somewhere. Is there any way to clear this cache, or do a graceful exit by any means while using the `script` command?

P.S. I don't want to remove the `-e` flag, since I want to know if something else caused a runtime error in my application.

Comment: Let it run, use `ps` to get the PID of `myApp`, then kill it with sigint. Does it still return `1`?

Comment: I didn't think about this scenario. I tried it now and it returned 0, but I don't understand this. What is the difference from the point of view of a running application?